# A dominate vector subset sum problem

Tags: np-hardness, np-complete, dynamic-programming, subset-sum

Let $k$ be some constants (e.g. one can take $k=2$ for simplexity), for any $u,v\in \mathbb{R}$, we say $u$ dominate $v$ if $\forall 1\le i\le k,~ u[i]\ge v[i]$, write it as $u\succ v$.

Consider the following problem:

> Let $v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n\in \mathbb{R}^k$, integer $m\le n$, and a target vector $t\in\mathbb{R}^k$, decide if there exist an index set $I\subset [n]$, such that
>   $$\sum_{i\in I}v_i\succ t,$$and $|I|\le m$

Is this problem NP-hard? (Note that, when $k$ is not constant but scale as $n$, this problem is NP-hard by reduction from set cover problem.)

In particular, is this problem hard for $k=2$? (Note that, there is a pseudo-polynomial dynamic programming algorithm for integer vectors).

Answer (score 2):

It's hard for $k\ge 2$ by a reduction from [Partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem). Let's first look at $k = 3$. Suppose that the input to Partition is the numbers $x_1, \ldots, x_n$, and their sum is $S$. For each $i$ create a vector $v_i$ whose first coordinate is $x_i$, second coordinate is $-x_i$, and the third coordinate is $0$. Add another vector $v_{n+1}$ with first coordinate $0$, second coordinate $S$, and last coordinate $1$. Define $t$ to have first and second coordinates $S/2$, and last coordinate $1$. Then any solution $I$ to this instance of your problem must include $n+1$, and the sum $\sum_{i \in I}{v_i}$ has first coordinate $\sum_{i \in I\setminus \{n+1\}}{x_i}$ and second coordinate $\sum_{i \in [n] \setminus I}{x_i}$, so it's only feasible if $I \setminus \{n+1\}$ is a valid solution to the Partition instance.

This can be extended to $k=2$ with a trick. Define the same instance but $v_i$ for $i \in [n]$ has only the first two coordinates. Let $A = \sum_{i=1}^n{|x_i|}$ and $b = \lceil \log_2 A\rceil$. Define $v_{n+1}$ to have first coordinate $2^b$, and second coordinate $S$, and $t$ to have first coordinate $2^b+S/2$ and second coordinate $S/2$. This forces the $b$-th bit (from the right) of the first coordinate of $\sum_{i \in I}{v_i}$ to be $1$, which can only happen if $n+1 \in I$. The rest is the same as above.

Comment: Yes, the reduction works. Is the problem still hard if we assume $v_i$ to be positive? Thanks.

Comment: If the vectors are positive then taking all of them maximizes all coordinates simultaneously. So, no, I don't think so.

Comment: Yes, but the problem has a cardinality constraint $m$ on the subsets. But anyway, I think your reduction can be adapted to the positive case by adding some constant to  the second coordinate to make them positive.

Comment: I see. I never noticed this in your formulation. This is a different question, however, it's probably better to post it separately.